# Low voltage in my garage circuit

Tags: electrical

I have a low voltage in my garage circuit, only 115 V instead of 120 V that I have in the rest of the house. A basic circuit tester shows the circuit is wired correctly, no open hot, neutral or ground and no reversed legs to the circuit. Any suggestions would be gratefully accepted. Thanks David

Comment: Is this an attached or a detached garage?

Comment: How far away from the main panel? Is there a sub panel in the garage.

Comment: Is there a significant load on the garage circuit when testing? If there is a load is it a 15 or 20A circuit?

Answer (score 1):

115 VAC is not abnormal.  If you wish to investigate further, measure the circuit breaker and see if that's any different.

Answer (score -1):

That’s not a problem at all considering it was called 110 volts for a long time. They upped the standard to 120 volts to get a little more power per ampere without toasting stuff. I live in Japan, where the standard voltage is 100 volts, and I’ve seen people bring stuff over here from North America and have it work without issue.